# Mock async static method with Moq

Tags: c#, asynchronous, moq, static-methods

so far I have been able to mock static methods by changing its signature to something like (pseudo)

```
public static Func<TResult> Foo = () => { return TResult; };
```

Then in test I could mock it via

```
MyClass.Foo = () => new TResult();
```

I am facing a new problem now.

There is a method with a signature something like:

```
public static async Task<TResult> FooBar(string obj1, string obj2)
```

I have changed it to

```
public static Func<string, string, Task<TResult>> FooBar = async (obj1, obj2)
```

and this compiles nicely, but I don't get it to compile for the test.

```
MyClass.FooBar(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()) => Task.FromResult(new TResult());
```

I know I should have await placed somewhere in the whole call but it just won't budge. 
What should be the proper way of mocking this delegate now?

Comment: Mocking static methods is the gateway to a world of hell. If you're unit testing use dependency injection properly. Don't use static methods at all, as they define static dependencies. If you must, use a wrapper class like the `HttpContextWrapper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
MyClass.FooBar = (string obj1, string obj2) => Task.FromResult(new TResult());
```

Note: not sure where your TResult is comming from, but as it is not possible to have instances of generic functions in C#, your TResult must be "known" at the time of writing the mock, i.e.

```
public static Func<string, string, Task<int>> Foo = Bar<int>;            
public static async Task<TResult> Bar<TResult>(string obj1, string obj2) where TResult : new()
    => await Task.FromResult(new TResult());
```

Comment: I was under the impression that I had to use It.IsAny<string>() as parameters where you simply used (obj1, obj2). 
That did the trick.